# How to get the object which represents the selected row in a slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a webpage with a slickgrid which renders an array of objects on a grid. I want to do some dynamic stuff (a master-detail like setup) when the selected row changes. However to be able to do this, I would need the data of the selected row. I know that the `grid.getCurrentCellNode()` function will give me the dom element of the current node, but what I am looking for is a javascript object. For instance, if I use an array of objects like the one below

```
data = [ 
        {id:1, name:'Khaja', dob:'26/07/1985'},
        {id:2, name:'Iqbal', dob:'26/07/1935'}
        ......
        ...
        ];
```

and if my selected row is the row with id equal to 2, I want to be able to retrive the object `{id:2, name:'Iqbal', dob:'26/07/1935'}` Is there a way through which I can get this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the onSelectedRowsChanged event and the getSelectedRows method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I assumed that slickgrid doesn't store the original data array to grid binding, But it seems that it does. So, now I can get the selected row indexes using the `getSelectedRows` and then look up that index in the original data source. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
data[i]={
    ID: json[i].ID,
    Name: json[i].Name,
    Description: json[i].Description,
    CreatedDate: myDate,
    makesub: "---",
    shared: json[i].IsShared
    };
.....

grid.onClick = function (e, row, cell) {
            if (columns[cell].id == "colname"){ 
                        // where colname is the column on which you want to trigger the click
            alert("clicked:"+row+", albumID:"+data[row].ID);
```

Comment: Could you try to explain your answer?