# SlickGrid onSelectedRowsChange firing twice when more than one row selected?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086865/how-to-get-the-object-which-represents-the-selected-row-in-a-slickgrid) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732115/slickgrid-callback-onrowselect) for background...)

Given:

```
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel());
grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function() { 
   row_ids = grid.getSelectedRows();
   console.log(row_ids);
});
```

... when I select one row (say, row 5), I get an output of

```
[4]
```

... which is what I would expect. However, CMD+Click or SHIFT+Click -ing another row (say, row 3) in addition to this row gives me an output of

```
[2]
[4, 2]
```

... which is NOT what I would expect (I would expect just `[4, 2]`). This seems to happen so long as the number of rows selected is `> 1`. So, if I were to continue to select another row (say, row 17), I would get this

```
[16]
[4, 2, 16]
```

I added a breakpoint on the `console.log` statement and verified that the `onSelectedRowsChanged` is being fired twice: once for the newly clicked row, and once for all the selected rows.

Why is this? I only want it fired ***once***, giving me the complete array of the selected rows. How would I accomplish this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: what version of SlickGrid are you using? I'm using a quite up-to-date checkout from the "v2 master" branch (maybe mid-january 2011) and didn't experience this problem

Comment: I'm using "SlickGrid v2.0 alpha", direct from the github page. I found the source of the problem... posting below...

Comment: My bad; updated the question above (rather than answering below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem (I've since discovered) lies in the row selection model `Slick.RowSelectionModel()`.

Specifically, when the row was selected, `handleActiveCellChange()` AND `handleClick()` were being called, each which calls `setSelectedRanges()`, while the former only sets it to the currently clicked row, and the latter sets it to all the selected rows.

I fixed this by unregistering in `init()` (inside `slick.rowSelectionModel.js`) `_grid.onActiveCellChanged` handler and moved the call inside `handleClick()`:

```
function init(grid) {
   _options = $.extend(true, {}, _defaults, options);
   _grid = grid;
   // _grid.onActiveCellChanged.subscribe(handleActiveCellChange);
   _grid.onKeyDown.subscribe(handleKeyDown);
   _grid.onClick.subscribe(handleClick);
}

...

function handleClick(e, data) {

   ...

   if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.metaKey) {
      handleActiveCellChange(e, data);
      return false;
   }

   ...

}
```

I don't know if this has been fixed by the author in "v2 master", as @fbuchinger said, and I know this fix is quick and dirty (this breaks keyboard navigation and selection between rows), but it works and gives me the expected behavior described in my question. Since I care more about the clicks working properly than the keyboard navigation, I'm sticking with this for now.

Anyone know of a better way?